# Java: Как можно перевести main поток в демон?

Tags: java, многопоточность, linux

В общем сейчас реализовано так, запускается дочерний поток в состоянии демона, а главный поток ждет его завершения, чтобы не возникало ни каких проблем вывод перенаправлен в два файла (out, err), а программа запускается просто в фоновом режиме (&).Так вот, пытался я главный (main) поток перевести в состояние демона, но Thread.setDaemon(true) как я понял должен вызываться перед Thread.start() (именно так реализован дочерний поток-демон).Ну и вопрос в следующем как можно main-поток перевести в состояние демона сразу же?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Демон -потоки позволяют описывать фоновые процессы, которые нужны только для обслуживания основных потоков выполнения и не могут существовать без них.
Несмотря на то, что демон -поток никогда не выходит из метода run(), виртуальная машина прекращает работу, как только все не- демон -потоки завершаются.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение, т.е. я так понимаю, что в Java нельзя сделать основной поток демоном. Оно конечно и так великолепно работает, просто хотел убедится, что это действительно нельзя сделать.